# How to checkout project as Angular project

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, svn

I would like to checkout an Angularjs project from SVN Repository in Eclipse. What I want is that I want to checkout the project as an Angular project. I have Angularjs plugin Webeclipse installed on my eclipse.

For example, when  I import a project, I can import it as an Angular project.
What is the right way to checkout an Angularjs project and use it with Webeclipse plugin ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the right answer,

After I checkout the project, Webeclipse plugin , initialize the project as Angular project if you select the project on project combo box.